# How to know what to catch with Try/Catch Block

Tags: java, try-catch

I'm simply trying to read in a text file with BufferedReader, and I'm using a `try-catch` block that is suppose to catch any `IOExceptions`. I thought it did, and even added a `FileNotFoundException` in case that was the problem. Yet I'm still getting :

**Error:** unreported exception java.lang.Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown

And I don't understand what part I'm not catching. Here's my code:

```
public Grade load(){

Grade newList = new Grade();
try {
  int year;
  String newLine;

  BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputName));

  while((newLine = inFile.readLine())!= null){

    year = Integer.parseInt(inFile.readLine());
    newList.addGrade(new Grade(year));  
  } 

  inFile.close();
}//try

 catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  System.out.println("Failed to copy the file:  "+e.getMessage());}
 catch(IOException e){
  System.out.println("Failed to copy the file:  "+e.getMessage());}

    return newList;
 }//load
```

Comment: What is `newList`, and what does `addGrade()` throw?

Comment: And you should be using `try-with-resources` to make sure that the `BufferedReader` is closed regardless of the outcome

Comment: There is also `new Grade(year)` which could be an exception source.  Since the compiler mentions `java.lang.Exception` explicitly, either `addGrade()` and/or the constructor to `Grade` are declared to throw `Exception`.  In Java, the exception you must check for are part of the signature of the method and will be declared in the `throws` clause of the method declaration.

Comment: Try using one `catch` clause with `Exception e` as the argument

Comment: @SamTebbs33 That would be a really bad way to deal with this.

Comment: @SamTebbs33 That works but isn't a good idea; what OP should instead do is add a `catch` clause with `Exception e` after the others. A better idea would be for OP to modify the constructor or method that throws `Exception` so that it throws one of its subclasses instead.

Comment: @azurefrog, I think I'm completely stupid. I don't really get `try-catch` block code, and I had it throw `Exception` instead of `IOException` and I think that's why ewh, TNT, and SamTebbs33's way worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume either Grade.addGrade method or Grade constructor is declared to throw java.lang.Exception

It is also a good practice to catch java.lang.NumberFormatException when using Integer.parse method.

Comment: Thank-you! That's what the problem seems to be! I assumed they were interchangeable. Could you explain what the difference exactly is? And thanks for the `NumberFormatException` tip, I'll be sure to add it in my code.

Comment: Exception is a base class, IOException extends Exception, FileNotFoundException extends IOException. By catching a base class you catch all the derived classes as well, but it does not work the other way around. You can find more information on this here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html

Answer (score 0):

#### Answers:

First of all, if you want to know what to catch (Or to be said better, what is thrown), you first need to look at the Java documentation. This shows you a detailed outline of every method of every officially supported class, so you best be looking at it before doing sensitive operations such as input/output.

So, what I recommend doing is putting an extra `catch` block at the end of your existing statement, and making it catch the `java.lang.Exception`, better known simply as the *master exception*, from which all other exceptions are derived from and extend.

This is not the most desirable fix for the problem, but it will not be as big a deal as putting an `else` statement at the end of a multi-if statement, in the sense that you are simply providing a fallback block in the event of all other blocks failing. This is simply an extra layer of protection that happens to satisfy the compiler.

#### Code Demo

This is simply demo code, and is simply meant to show what *should* be done. As I do not know what your project is, and/or what you are doing, I will just show the barebones of what you need to do, and in know way can I be responsible for anything happening as a direct or indirect result of this code being used in the final product.

```
public Grade load(){

Grade newList = new Grade();
try {
  int year;
  String newLine;

  BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputName));

  while((newLine = inFile.readLine())!= null){

    year = Integer.parseInt(inFile.readLine());
    newList.addGrade(new Grade(year));  
  } 

  inFile.close();
}//try

 catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  System.out.println("Failed to copy the file:  "+e.getMessage());}
 catch(IOException e){
  System.out.println("Failed to copy the file:  "+e.getMessage());}

    return newList;
 }catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
     //...OTHER HANDLING CODE. THE ABOVE COULD BE LEFT BLANK...//
 }//load
```